# Trouble passing a 2d array to function after malloc

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, malloc, function-call

I've gotten back into C recently after a long absence, and I can't for the life of me remember how to pass a 2D matrix to a function and use it after mallocating it. I believe I've passed the pointer correctly, but I can't seem to actually access anything in the matrix and can't figure out why.

This is what I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void matrixOperation(int *arr, int m, int n)
{
    
    printf("in matrixOperation\n ");
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%d\n", *((arr+i*n) + j));
}
 
int main()
{
    int i,j,count;
    int row, col;
    
    
    //------------------------------
    printf("Number of rows?\n  ");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    
    printf("Number of columns?\n  ");
    scanf("%d", &col);
    
    //------------------------------
    
    
    int* arr[row];
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        arr[i] = (int*)malloc(col * sizeof(int));
    
    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
            arr[i][j] = ++count;
 
 
 for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
            printf("%d\n",arr[i][j]);
 
 
 
    // We can also use "print(&arr[0][0], m, n);"
    matrixOperation((int *)arr, row, col);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        free(arr[i]);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

The goal was to have it accept user input for the size of the matrix, fill each index with a count and then pass it to a function which would print it out. However when I try it the print statement just outputs random numbers which I assume are what the pointers are pointing at.

I would like matrixOperation to print out the same thing as the print statement in main and I can't quite figure out what I've done wrong.

Comment: You are passing `int**` to the function.  Not `int*`.  Why cast in the first place?

Comment: Learn to distinguish these 3 cases:  (1) An array of arrays (this is a standard 2d array), (2) An array of pointers (this is typically used for jagged arrays, but it's an alternate way of implementing a 2d array), (3) A 1d array that's used to manually implement a 2d array (by converting two indices into a single flat index).  You need to be consistent.  Your `main` is using case (2), while your function is trying to treat it as case (3).  Obviously that can't possibly work.  Think about what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You declared an array of pointers:

```
int* arr[row];
```

So pass this array to the function.

The function will be declared like:

```
void matrixOperation(int **arr, int m, int n)
{
    
    printf("in matrixOperation\n ");
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%d\n", *( *( arr + i ) + j ) );
}
```

and call the function like:

```
matrixOperation( arr, row, col );
```

Though it will be better to define the function like:

```
void matrixOperation(int **arr, int m, int n)
{
    printf("in matrixOperation\n ");

    for ( int i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            printf("%d ", *( *( arr + i ) + j ) );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

Pay attention to that this expression with the pointer arithmetic:

```
*( *( arr + i ) + j )
```

can be rewritten using the subscript operator the following way:

```
arr[i][j]
```

The both expressions are equivalent each other.

As for your call of the function with casting the array designator:

```
matrixOperation((int *)arr, row, col);
```

then it is wrong because you do not have one extent of memory. You allocated several extents of memory.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask why your matrixOperation is better? I don't doubt it, but I would like to know for future.

Comment: @AlbertoCattaneo Because it outputs the array indeed as a matrix row by row.:)

Comment: Don't write `*(arr + i)`.  It's bad form.  Instead, write `a[i]`.  Similarly, `*(*(arr+i)+j)` is just `a[i][j]`, which is a much clearer way to write it.  Don't fight the language.

Comment: @TomKarzes he is learning pointers in C and in his original code there are used such expressions. It is very important to understand such expressions.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow In situations like that, it's always best to include the preferred way as well, explaining that it's equivalent.

Comment: @TomKarzes I cannot agree. In his question he intentionally uses the pointer arithmetic and it is important to show how correctly to use it for an array of pointers. Such a knowledge is very useful.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Sure, there's nothing wrong with showing how to use pointer arithmetic, but you should *always* show a better way to do something, if there is a better way.  Otherwise you're reinforcing bad habits.  If this were being graded in a CS course at a top school, points would be taken off for not using the proper array index syntax.

Comment: @TomKarzes I am sure he is learning the pointer arithmetic. And  this exercise designed specially for investigating it. And I am sure he already knows how to use the subscript operator because that is basics. So the accent is on how to use the pointer arithmetic.  So your comments are irrelevant.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow This *entire question* was incredibly basic, so no, OP does *not* understand arrays, or pointers, or array syntax.  And your answer, while showing *one way* to make the code work, does little to teach the best way to implement a solution.

Comment: @TomKarzes While I appreciate your focus on good form, I was mainly trying to remember how pointer arithmetic worked again after a long time. I'm aware that doing arithmetic like that is less than ideal but as a way to visualize the way the array is read I appreciate the clarity it offers.

Comment: @AlbertoCattaneo They're the same thing.  The `[]` operator is defined as `a[i]` is `*(a+i)`.  Further, it's commutative:  You can also write `i[a]`, which most people don't realize and is very bad form, but it works.  You can think of it almost like a macro.  The point is that the underlying arithmetic is the same.  The `[]` form is just far more readable than the explicit pointer addition form.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function signature and you should be able to use the same piece of code.

```
void matrixOperation(int **arr, int m, int n)
{
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%d\n",arr[i][j]);
}
```

Call with:

```
matrixOperation(arr, row, col);
```

Remember when an array is passed to a function, it "decays" into a pointer.  You have an array of pointers.  That decays to a pointer to pointers.